# Page saving script

Tags: save, html, contenteditable

Specifically I'm looking for a way to save the webpage on the server (It's kind of a hard to phrase question so google isn't giving me anything useful).

I would like to add this function to a button somewhere on the page, then technically anyone who has access to this ContentEditable page can save their progress. Yes I'm aware of the insecurity of this.

What's the best/easiest way to do this? PHP? Javascript?

Comment: @Drayavahus-tdi And how would I implement that?